# Initialization in if statement existed before C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17

Accidentally the following code was found:

```
if (bool result = f()) {
    // Do the stuff
}
```

It was compiled with `gcc 4.9.2` and `MSVS 2013`.

The following code compiles and prints `False!`:

```
#include <iostream>

bool foo() {
    return false;
}

void bar() {
    if (bool result = foo()) {
        std::cout << "True!\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "False!\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    bar();

    return 0;
}
```

I thought that this (except syntax) functionality is available only since `C++17`.

Do I understand it wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Do I understand it wrong?

Jup. It was always allowed to have a declaration within the *condition* of an if statement. What is new in C++17 is that you can have a initializer and a condition:

```
if (int A = 0; ++A == 1);
//  ^^^^^^^^^
//  new part
```

---

For those asking why this is a useful feature, here's an example that I like from Reddit:

```
std::map<int, std::string> Map;
// ...

if (auto[it, inserted] = Map.insert(std::pair(10, "10")); inserted)
    ; // do something with *it.
```

Comment: Now I see the difference. Anyway I was surprised by this feature.

Comment: @SombreroChicken: You're a production machine.

Comment: The new syntaxe is also to avoid `++A == 1`

Comment: How is this feature useful?  I don't see an obvious use cases

Comment: @Bathsheba Your machine is a production.

Comment: @MatthewFisher the scope of `A` is restricted to the `if` body. How would you do that without the new feature?

Comment: @MatthewFisher 1. Keep variable scope as small as possible; 2. Error propagation

Comment: @MatthewFisher: `if (int x = foo(); x > 42)` You can use the result of `foo()` throughout the conditional (note that this works in any chained `else` too!) _and_ it saves you creating a brand new scope around the `if` just for `x`, _or_ not bothering and "leaking" `x` to the surroundings. Plus it is grammatically elegant. Have a read of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r0.html; it's pretty compelling.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax in c++17 is different:

```
if(int foo = result(); foo == 1)
```

The new notation first declares  the variable and then makes a test on it. It fixes the issue of assignment and condition test in the same statement that could lead to mistakes.

Comment: Indeed, fixed! @Alex, there is no functional difference, it was created to forbid mistakes when doing declaration, or assignment, and comparisons at the same time.

Comment: No functional difference in this very trivial case, which is not really what the new syntax was created for

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In c++17, we can initialize and then test a condition in if statement.

Example :

```
 if( bool result = foo(); result ) {
    std::cout << "True!\n";
 } else {
    std::cout << "False!\n";
 }
```

It helps us write a cleaner code, if the scope of the variable is just limited to the if statement.

The above will look neat than

```
 bool result = foo();
 if( result ) {
    std::cout << "True!\n";
 } else {
    std::cout << "False!\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

c++17 also allows this potentially confusing construct:

```
int bar();
bool query();
void foo(int, bool);

int main()
{
    if (int x = bar() ; bool y = query())
    {
        foo(x, y);
    }
    else
    {
        foo(x * 2, y);
    }
}
```